# How do you version ViewModel when validation rule change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We work on a multigenerational project. In past whenever there would be modifications to the view layout, we would create a version of that view and would tie in the ViewModel, so ViewModel will be kind of versioned.

Now let us say if the rule set has been changed in the view but not the View layout itself, how would you tie in another version of ViewModel, when all you have is just one view?

**EDIT:** The following code snippet may help to describe my situation.

Version 1.0.0 Development

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class V_Time : CCSUserControl
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public V_Time(IVM_Time viewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
}
```

When in future a request is made to change the layout, we will do something like the following

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class V_Time_1_2_0 : CCSUserControl
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public V_Time_1_2_0(IVM_Time_1_2_0 viewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But my problem is, I am not going to be creating a new xaml hence no xaml.cs either, yet I want to have another version of ViewModel to handle a request which asks to reverse the enable/disable rule.

Comment: Hard to understand the problem. Could you post some code before/after to describe your problem a little more detailed? IMHO best practice is to version the assembly (or assemblies). If you are using a proper source control the files are "versioned" by the source control.

Comment: No.  No though.  Nope.  No.  This is all the no.  Nope.  Don't even.  No.

Comment: @Will Please elaborate.

Comment: *Why* version?  It's not like you'll have different versions of the application using dissimilar ViewModels.  You update the entire app (ViewModel and all) and re-deploy.  I don't see any reason to version the ViewModel.  Now, if you're re-using the ViewModel as a model that is used externally, then don't do that--using mapping instead.  Then version your models and maintain different mapping code to get each version into the one-and-only ViewModel.